# For-in Loop Through Array of Structs; Index Out of Range?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

The following results in "Fatal error: Index out of range" in Swift 4 Playgrounds.  I'm fairly new to Swift; shouldn't the answer be "10"? Thanks!

```
struct Example {
var partOne: Int
var partTwo: Int
var partThree: Int
 }

var one = Example(partOne: 10, partTwo: 11, partThree: 12)
var two = Example(partOne: 10, partTwo: 11, partThree: 12)

var arrayOfExamples = [Example]()


print(arrayOfExamples[0].partOne)
```

Comment: Why would it be 10? Your array is empty.

Comment: the _line_ `var arrayOfExamples = [Example]()` **intializes** the array. It's like creating a new house. But how many people are in the house? `0`. No one! You need to add people to the house. You do add by using `append`. Similarly in your case...after that _line_ do `arrayOfExamples.append(one)`. Do the same thing for `two`. It won't be empty anymore

Answer (score 3):

Try below code

```
struct Example {
    var partOne: Int
    var partTwo: Int
    var partThree: Int
}

var one = Example(partOne: 10, partTwo: 11, partThree: 12)
var two = Example(partOne: 10, partTwo: 11, partThree: 12)

var arrayOfExamples = [one, two]

print(arrayOfExamples[0].partOne)  // 10
print(arrayOfExamples[1].partOne)  // 10
```

**Output** : 10, 10

Using For-In Loop

```
for i in arrayOfExamples {
  print(i.partOne)
}
```

**Output** : 10, 10